# Problem with picom on arch with multiple tiling window managers

Tags: arch-linux, bspwm, picom

Problem:
When starting picom with any config (even an empty one) on a pretty fresh arch installation with nvidia-open drivers, something weird happens when using multiple windows on different workspaces. When having picom started, the windows on a workspace seem to be overlapped with windows from other workspaces, after switching from one workspace to another.

Note: i am currently using bspwm but the problem remains on different window managers e.g. qtile, i3, awesome, etc. (haven't tried it on floating wm's)

[image: This is a screenshot without picom]

[image: This is a screenshot with picom]